# Any fix for Firefox's DNS Cache?

Tags: firefox, caching, browser, dns

Firefox has a powerful feature in which it caches DNS lookups to improve speed.

I have a situation where this is causing more problem then it is fixing.  I manage a website and we recently migrated our site to a new, upgraded server.  This server has a different public IP address.  We updated our DNS records and everything is correct, but some customers using FireFox are reporting that they are still seeing the "site under construction" page we put up on the old server before the migration.  I was running into this problem as well.

The only fix I found that worked was to flush the browser cache, selecting "Everything" from the dropdown, and then closing the browser and re-launching.  That works, but it's not a "solution" when you consider that we're dealing with customers all across the country, many of whom are not computer literate, and most of them don't even take the time to let us know that they are experiencing a problem.  We are losing business because customers who don't know any better see a "site under construction" message and move on, probably spending their money on some other site.

There needs to be some sort of way to tell FireFox that its cache for this site is outdated and it needs to update.  But I have no idea how to do that (or if it's even possible) and I can't find any information about it.  Every "solution" to this problem involves flushing the browser cache.  Again, that works, but it's a reactive solution when someone happens to call in to support.  We need a proactive solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Won't help this time, but did you drop the TTL prior to updating the A record?

Comment: Does Ctrl-f5 flush the DNS cache? In which case you could place instructions to do that on the "under construction" page. You could also make your old server redirect to your new server's IP address.

Comment: I don't believe we did drop the TTL, but the migration was handled by our site host and neither I nor anyone else on my team are IT admins or know enough about this to have known to do that.  I guess I know now!  Regarding CTRL-F5, it does not flush.  It will reload and not use the cache, but if you then just hit F5 you get the same problem again.

Comment: BTW, thanks for the edits, Adrian.  I'll try to make my posts more reader friendly in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's no way for you to remote visitors FirFox, cuz it's not safe for the users.

The best way is to alert the visitors on the old site that they should refresh the DNS cache. Find the option in firefox for "Clear Recent History" and then select everything and check all the boxes under details.

The 2nd way is using this add-on: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dns-cache/

The 3rd way,

- type about:config in Firefox’s address bar
- acknowledge the warning that appears next
- find an entry called network.dnsCacheExpiration and set it’s value to 0
- if there’s no such entry, create a new integer item with the name above and a value of 0
- now go back and change the value to 3600

Comment: I figured there'd be no easy way.  Thank you for the detailed response.  I'll probably add some instructions to the page.  At least we know going forward if we make any more changes!

Comment: @BrianVPS Maybe add some instructions to the page is the best way to solve this problem. ;-)

Comment: In my Firefox 28 Mac the entry is set to 2592000 by default.